# Array of 2 words Greensock Tween

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I'm trying to achieve a simple effect on 2 words array using the greensock engine.

It's working but the timing is off. I want them to be coordinate and with an alpha in between the simple way all I want to I just to show one word after the other in repeat and yoyo right now I almost got it it's just not a good timing.

```
var allnum2:Array = [text1, text2];
Timeline.appendMultiple(
  TweenMax.allFrom(allnum2, .7, {
    alpha: 0,
    repeat: 7,
    yoyo: true,
    ease:Strong.easeInOut
  }, .7)
, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how this code can work at all, since Timeline is not a class from the Greensock api.

Try this:

```
var allnum2:Array = [text1, text2];
var tl:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();
tl.appendMultiple(
  TweenMax.allFrom(allnum2, .7, {
    alpha: 0,
    repeat: 7,
    yoyo: true,
    ease:Strong.easeInOut
  }, .7)
, 1);
```

Why are you using a TimeLine? allFrom would be enough to do your simple tween.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry ive just seen it know i figured it out, it does work you dont need to call private function to implement greensock api, timeline does work and its in as3 not js.